# Array of objects, compare with other arrays and filter

Tags: javascript

I need some help with this, I have to filter arr objects by the elements of regions and years, I tried with filter method but I can't figure out how to achieve this, thanks in advance.

```js
let arr = [
        { id: 1, region: ["china"], year: ["1990"] },
        { id: 2, region: ["china"], year: ["2010"] },
        { id: 3, region: ["taiwan"], year: ["1990"] },
        { id: 4, region: ["corea"], year: ["1990"] },
        { id: 5, region: ["corea"], year: ["2010"] },
      ];

let regions = ["china", "taiwan"];
let years = ["1990"];
```

```js
let expectedOutput = [{ id: 1, region: ["china"], year: ["1990"] },
                  { id: 2, region: ["china"], year: ["2010"] },
                  { id: 3, region: ["taiwan"], year: ["1990"] },
                  { id: 4, region: ["corea"], year: ["1990"] }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter it

```js
let arr = [
        { id: 1, region: ["china"], year: ["1990"] },
        { id: 2, region: ["china"], year: ["2010"] },
        { id: 3, region: ["taiwan"], year: ["1990"] },
        { id: 4, region: ["corea"], year: ["1990"] },
        { id: 5, region: ["corea"], year: ["2010"] },
      ];

let regions = ["china", "taiwan"];
let years = ["1990"];

let result = arr.filter(({region, year}) => region.some(el => regions.includes(el)) || year.some(year => years.includes(year)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking a hard wired approach, you could take an object's entries as filters with the wanted key and possible values.

```js
let array = [{ id: 1, region: ["china"], year: ["1990"] }, { id: 2, region: ["china"], year: ["2010"] }, { id: 3, region: ["taiwan"], year: ["1990"] }, { id: 4, region: ["corea"], year: ["1990"] }, { id: 5, region: ["corea"], year: ["2010"] }],
    region = ["china", "taiwan"],
    year = ["1990"],
    filters = Object.entries({ region, year }),
    result = array.filter(o => filters.some(([k, a]) => a.some(v => o[k].includes(v))));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @ Nice approach. But this does'nt give the desired result. Your approach is fine for all combinations of region "AND" year. Thanks!!

Comment: @RahulSingh, just change to `some`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
let arr = [
    { id: 1, region: ["china"], year: ["1990"] },
    { id: 2, region: ["china"], year: ["2010"] },
    { id: 3, region: ["taiwan"], year: ["1990"] },
    { id: 4, region: ["corea"], year: ["1990"] },
    { id: 5, region: ["corea"], year: ["2010"] }
  ];

let regions = ["china", "taiwan"];
let years = ["1990"];


let result = arr.filter((row) => {
    if (regions.includes(row.region[0]) ) {
        return row;
    } else if (years.includes(row.year[0])) {
        return row;
    }

});
console.log(result.length);
for (row of result) {
    console.log(row);
}
```

output:

```
4
{ id: 1, region: [ 'china' ], year: [ '1990' ] }
{ id: 2, region: [ 'china' ], year: [ '2010' ] }
{ id: 3, region: [ 'taiwan' ], year: [ '1990' ] }
{ id: 4, region: [ 'corea' ], year: [ '1990' ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
        { id: 1, region: ["china"], year: ["1990"] },
        { id: 2, region: ["china"], year: ["2010"] },
        { id: 3, region: ["taiwan"], year: ["1990"] },
        { id: 4, region: ["corea"], year: ["1990"] },
        { id: 5, region: ["corea"], year: ["2010"] },
      ];

let regions = ["china", "taiwan"];
let years = ["1990"];  

arr=arr.filter(obj => regions.includes(obj.region[0]) || years.includes(obj.year[0]));

console.log(arr);
```